# Check whether buffer is in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, major-mode, variables

I want to programmatically check whether the current buffer is in `org` mode. I know that major modes should usually define the variable `<modename>-mode`, i.e., `org-mode` should be a defined variable.

However, if I execute `describe-variable` in an org buffer, I don't see any `org-mode`. Now, I'm not sure whether `describe-variable` works for buffer-local variables, so I typed `(message org-mode)` into my org buffer and ran `eval-last-sexp`. This gives me the error `(void-variable org-mode)`, so I guess that org mode does not define any `org-mode` variable.

What is the correct way to check whether a buffer is in org mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I know that major modes should usually define the variable -mode, i.e., org-mode should be a defined variable.

Not quite: a major mode should set the variable `mode-name` to the "pretty name" for the mode (i.e., the one that will appear in the modeline), and the variable `major-mode` to the major mode's command symbol (i.e., `org-mode` in this case). You can test if the current buffer is in `org-mode` with:

```elisp
(string-equal major-mode "org-mode")

;; or equivalently:

(string-equal mode-name "Org")
```

These conventions are explained in the Emacs Lisp manual, [(elisp) Major Mode Conventions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Major-Mode-Conventions.html).

Comment: Also ...:  `(eq major-mode 'org-mode)`.   Unlike `org-mode`, some modes may change their `mode-name` depending upon certain criteria ... and the `major-mode` remains the same ...